# VTK + Cmake -> USE_VTK_RENDERING error

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, visualization, vtk

I am a begineer in VTK library and I have a problem with run this project:

http://web.mit.edu/16.225/dv/VTK/Examples/ImageProcessing/Cxx/

In CMakeLists there is 'if' condition:

**IF(NOT VTK_USE_RENDERING)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Example ${PROJECT_NAME} requires VTK_USE_RENDERING.")
ENDIF(NOT VTK_USE_RENDERING)**

but during the configuration in CMake error apears:

**CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (MESSAGE):
  Example ImageProcessing requires VTK_USE_RENDERING.**

Proble is that there is no VTK_USE_RENDERING entry in CMake. So how I can solve this problem? Should I use QT?

I would be grateful for any response!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It means when you compiled VTK from source you should have enabled `VTK_USE_RENDERING `. Reconfigure vtk with cmake-gui enabling `VTK_USE_RENDERING ` then generate then rebuild vtk.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It is quite obvious but there is no VTK_USE_RENDERING entry in CMake 3.2.2 version. So how to enable this?

Comment: You will have to recompile vtk itself not your application. Did you look for `VTK_USE_RENDERING` when you configured vtk with cmake?

Comment: ***Should I use QT?*** I say probably yes but it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: drescherjm - There is no VTK_USE_RENDERING like in attached photo from web:

http://www.cs.uakron.edu/~xiao/visualization/VTK-Installation-Tutorial_files/image022.jpg

Maybe I should use earlier version of CMake [not 3.2.2] but I am afraid that it may cause another incompatibility errors. So how to do it in 3.2.2? I added VTK_USE_RENDERING entry manualy and set it to "TRUE" value but it doesnt't work - another errors appers.

Comment: Please find attached a photo what i see in CMake during building projects with filter "render". 

http://postimg.org/image/4rn6tpxq3/

This is screen from CMake 3.0.0 - earliest version which supports Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. I will be grateful for any help because I'am stuck..

Comment: It may be that your VTK is too new. I am still using vtk-5.10.X

Comment: What I found out is that in VTK version newer than 6.0.0 there is no USE_VTK_RENDERING entry in CMake. Problem is that in VTK 5.10.X there is no possibility to compaile project for Visual Studio 2013 which I have already installed.

I tried out to installed VS2010 but there is too many crashees due to installed too new frameworks like .NET and I am afraid that i can not delete most of them because of other programs...

Are you using VS? If yes, which version?

I don't belive that there is no option to compaile it in VTK greater than 6.0.0....

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

VTK greater or equal than 6.0 version should use this CMakeFile.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5 FATAL_ERROR) 
project(ImageProcessing) 

find_package(VTK REQUIRED NO_MODULE) 
include(${VTK_USE_FILE}) 

add_executable(ImageSlicing ImageSlicing.cxx) 
target_link_libraries(ImageSlicing ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```